# Subject triggering only once after pipe and mergeMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is the declaration for the subject and observable:

```js
private subscription: Subscription;
private subject = new Subject();
public observable$: Observable<any> = defer(() => this.subject)
```

I am having an issue with resolving a flow involving the flattening of the following nested subscriptions:

```js
// This works

this.subscription = this.observable$.subscribe(
    (response) => {
        console.log("triggered")
        return this.otherService.function(response).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                // handle if success
            },
            (error) => {
                // handle if fail
            }
        )
    },
);
```

Now, I've tried using a pipe and a mergeMap/switchMap/concatMap but none of them seem to work. The `console.log("triggered")` is only called once, despite the subject changing values over time. Exemple:

```js
this.subsctiption = this.observable$.pipe(
    concatMap((response) => {
        console.log("triggered")
        return this.otherService.function(response)
    })
).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        // handle if success
    },
    (error) => {
        // handle if error
    }
)
```

Finally, this is how the subject is calling next. It's a function handle from an event output from child component

```js
public handleNextValue(nextValue) {
  console.log(nextValue) // this also prints successfully so the value is passed correctly
  this.subject.next(nextValue);
}
```

What I am doing wrong here? Why the first approach works while the 2nd is only triggering the console.log only once?

---

Later edit:
Thanks to Chris Hamilton there is a stackblitz example **which actually works** as intended: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppxhpg?file=src/app/app.component.ts
However this makes me even more confused on what might be wrong inside my code, since the subject's next value is correctly called.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ppxhpg?file=src/app/app.component.ts. Most likely your `handleNextValue()` function isn't actually getting called.

Comment: Thank you for the stackblitz. It actually is called, because i have a console.log before the `this.subject.next(nextValue)` and it prints the correct value...

Comment: See if you can fork the stackblitz and reproduce the behaviour. Must be caused by something you haven't shown here.

Comment: What's the point of using `defer` here? The Observable factory function (i.e. the function you pass to defer) does not create a new Observable any time it is subscribed but returns always the same Subject instance. `defer` goal is to make sure that at any subscription a new Observable is subscribed.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. However might this be the case in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

`concatMap` operator subscribed to the Observable returned from its projection function and keeps re-emiting its notifications until it **completes**. Any subsequent emission from the source Observable is stacked inside `concatMap()`. And this is the problem when using `concatMap()` with Subjects. Subjects don't complete until you call `Subject.complete()`.

So it looks like the problem is that `this.otherService.function(response)` never completes and that's why `console.log("triggered")` prints only once.

Comment: I've also tried with mergeMap and same results. What else can i try?

Comment: Then create a reproducible demo